# SQLite query select between 2 records on same condition

Tags: sqlite, time, count, between

i am trying to count (in minutes) between two records on 1 table and WHERE clause is the same condition.

```
_id  | venue_id | act_time  | status |
 1   |  1       | 13:30     | 0      |
 2   |  1       | 15:40     | 1      |
 3   |  2       | 13:03     | 0      |
 4   |  2       | 16:06     | 1      |
```

when i exec query like this :

```
SELECT _id, venue_id, status, (julianday(act_time IN (SELECT act_time FROM reports WHERE venue_id='1' AND status='1')) - julianday(act_time))*1440 AS duration FROM reports WHERE venue_id='1' AND status='0'
```

but, the result show the wrong calculation

Please help me what is the correct query for this problem?

so, if i count the duration between 15:40 - 13:30 (at venue_id='1') = 130 minutes.

thank you.

Comment: Why do you multiply the number of days with 1440?

Comment: i am not sure. I just want to convert julianday to minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN operator checks whether the value on the left side is contained in the set of values on the right side, and returns a boolean result (0 or 1).

You just want to use the `act_time` value directly; drop `act_time IN`.